# cdk pipe-line gets errors

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

```
import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
import * as pipelines from '@aws-cdk/pipelines';


class PipelineStack extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props: cdk.StageProps) {
      super(scope, id, props);
  
      // Create the CDK pipeline
      const pipeline = new pipelines.CodePipeline(this, 'Pipeline', {
        pipelineName: 'ServerlessPipelineDemo',
        synth: new pipelines.ShellStep('Synth', {
          // Use a connection created using the AWS console to authenticate to GitHub
          // Other sources are available.
          input: CodePipelineSource.connection('taimos/cdk-serverless-demo-pipeline', 'main', {
            connectionArn: 'arn:aws:codestar-connections:us-east-1:222222222222:connection/abc', // Created using the AWS console
          }),
          commands: [
            'npm ci && npm ci --prefix lambda',
            'npx cdk synth',
          ],
        }),
      });
    }
  }
```

I got an error in the line `const pipeline = new pipelines.CodePipeline(this,`

**Error is "this: this
Argument of type 'this' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Construct'.
Type 'PipelineStack' is not assignable to type 'Construct'.
Property 'onValidate' is protected but type 'Construct' is not a class derived from 'Construct'."**

package.json

```
{
  "name": "cloud",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "bin": {
    "cloud": "bin/cloud.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc && npm run copyDependencies",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "test": "jest",
    "cdk": "cdk",
    "clean": "rm -rf ./cdk.out",
    "synth": "cdk synth --app \"npx ts-node ./bin/user-manager-serverless.ts\"",
    "deploy": "npm run synth && cdk deploy --app ./cdk.out/ --require-approval=never",
    "buildAndDeploy": "npm run build && npm run synth && cdk deploy --app ./cdk.out/ --require-approval=never",
    "copyDependencies": "copy-node-modules . node_modules_layer/nodejs/"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@aws-cdk/assert": "1.74.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway": "1.74.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-cognito": "1.74.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-dynamodb": "1.74.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-iam": "1.74.0",
    "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.71",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.10",
    "@types/node": "10.17.27",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.0",
    "aws-cdk": "1.74.0",
    "aws-lambda": "^1.0.6",
    "jest": "^26.4.2",
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.0",
    "ts-node": "^8.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.7",
    "copy-node-modules": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-cdk/core": "1.74.0",
    "aws-xray-sdk-core": "^3.2.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.16",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline": "^1.95.1",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline-actions": "^1.95.1",
    "@aws-cdk/pipelines": "^1.95.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are the `@aws-cdk/core` and `pipeline` dependencies updated to the same version?

Comment: I have updated the package.json

Answer (score 2):

Your problem may be mismatched `package.json` cdk dependency versions.  The core package (where `Construct` lives in v1) is set to be exactly version 1.74, which won't match the the pipeline's version.  This sometimes causes compatability errors.  To fix it, add a `^` to all your `@aws-cdk` dependencies.

```json
"@aws-cdk/core": "1.74.0"           // exactly 1.74
"@aws-cdk/pipelines": "^1.95.1"     // compatible with v1.95
```

The [current CDK versions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/versions.html) are 1.137 and 2.3.0 (as of Jan 2022).